# Different lists Random

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

First, I generate random numbers (let say 1000 elements), how to know how many first elements that have sum is smaller or greater than 500?

Second, I will generate 4 lists of random numbers. Every number distributed in each list has no repetition, and if sum of the all lists are arise fixed value, the random generating will be stoped.
example: 1-4 lists; (1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,10), (11,12,13,14,15), (16,17,18,19,20);
sum of 4 lists is 210.

How I run the comand like "Give me 4 lists random numbers, no repetiton, if the sum = 210 stop random."?

thank you for the answer

Comment: I need to know how I can solve the problem with Wolfram-Mathematica.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This reports the number of first elements of `rand` to exceed 500.

```
rand = RandomInteger[10, 1000];

Catch[total = 0;
 Map[If[(total += First[#]) > 500, Throw[#[[2, 1]]]] &, 
  MapIndexed[List, rand]]]
```

> 103

Second question

"Every number distributed in *each* lists has no repetition."

`RandomSample` is useful for this.  Adding a counter `n`, can be omitted.

```
n = 0;

While[True,
 n++;
 total = Total@Flatten[lists = Table[RandomSample[Range[50], 5], 4]];
 If[total < 500, Break[]]]
lists
Row[{n, " loops"}]
```

> {{36, 30, 25, 9, 10}, {36, 22, 44, 13, 2}, {9, 24, 34, 7, 47}, {5, 28, 15, 36, 22}}
>
> 4 loops

36 appears in 2 lists, but each list itself has no repetitions.

Comment: The `total < 500` test needs to be done after setting `total`. Code above will just return the first generated list irrespective of it's total.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Oh yes. Fixed that.

Comment: Thank you brother, I get it.

Comment: What about my questions,

Comment: I have list of number, (let say 1000 elements), how to know how many first elements that have sum is smaller or greater than 500? Thnak you

Comment: @SyamsulHidayatDaud I have added to my answer.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen  A more functional way to find the first element of sum of `rand` to exceed 500 `rand // Accumulate // FirstPosition[x_ /; x > 500]`

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi That's very neat.

Comment: I get it. Thank You Brother